# Accessing SVG children in Safari

Tags: javascript, svg, safari

I load a SVG file with ajax and pass the SVG to a javascript function like this:

```
var svg = $(xml).find('svg');
map.addSlopeLayer(svg[0]);
```

Inside the function I access the children of the SVG:

```
var gs = svg.children;
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome but when I try it in Safari svg.children is undefined.

Is there an error in how I try to access the children or is there another way to access them in Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the solution for this a while ago and forgot to post it. As mentioned in the other answer Safari simply does not support the `children` property for SVG Elements the code I used to work around this is as follows:

```
var svgChildren = svg.children || svg.childNodes;

for (var i=0; i < svgChildren.length; i++){
  if (svgChildren[i].nodeType == 3) continue;

  //do something with the svg elements
}
```

Since `childNodes` also returns text nodes I filter them out using `if (svgChildren[i].nodeType == 3) continue;`

Answer (score 0):

In Safari, trying to read `children` on a SVG Elmeent will **always** return `undefined` that is because, sadly, it is not supported. Try using `childNodes` instead.